useState hook not functioning properly
So I am creating a clone of Google Gemini using React js and I am keeping a useState hook to keep the track of the chat history in the format that gemini API requires (array of objects where each object has one property saying is it user or model and other property is object with just one property, the text). The problem is that when I give it one input the hook stores 1 input then response then again same input and again the same response whereas it should store only 1 input and 1 response.
The function's code is :
const handleRun = async () => {
  setCall((prev) => prev + 1);
  console.log(call);
  if (input !== "") {
    console.log(conversationHistory);
    const response = await run(conversationHistory, input);
    setConversationHistory((prevHistory) => [
      ...prevHistory,
      { role: "user", parts: [{ text: input }] },
      { role: "model", parts: [{ text: response }] },
    ]);
    console.log(conversationHistory);
    setInput("");
  }
};

enter image description here

create a new array that combines the user message and the response with the existing history:


setConversationHistory([
  ...conversationHistory,
  { role: 'user', parts: [{ text: input }] },
  { role: 'model', parts: [{ text: response }] },
]);



